# How to get all the names from all the tags from form with Bottle Python as dict?

Tags: python, html, jinja2, bottle

Could you help me with the following question?
How can I get all the names from all the tags form with the library Bottle on Python as a dict?

Because actually the request.forms only provides me the last set of "names" from the HTML tags.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the request.forms into a dict.  Honestly I do this with every project so it can handle both query and form data:

```
def merge_dicts(*args):
    result = {}
    for dictionary in args:
        result.update(dictionary)
    return result

payload = merge_dicts(dict(request.forms), dict(request.query.decode()))
```

Example:

```
@post("/api")
def API():
    payload = merge_dicts(dict(request.forms), dict(request.query.decode()))
    print(payload)
```